# "Should have" type question

Tags: past-tense, questions, modal-verbs

I would like to know which one of these two questions is correct, grammar-wise?

> What should I have done?
>   *or*
>   What should have I done?

I would appreciate an explanation, too.

Comment: Never heard **What should have I done.** Where did you find this?

Comment: Some people contract _should've_ and move it as a unit, producing _What should've I done?_ But it's fairly rare, and only when contracted in speech. Ditto with _could've_.

Answer (score 2):

The only inversion needed is applied to the auxiliary, which in this case is *should*:

> *What should I have done?*
>   NOT <s>*What should have I done?*</s>

Answer (score 0):

if so no grammar  mistake

> What should have I done?

but i suggest

> What should I have done?

because it is more powerful and more

> What else should I have done?
>   What should I have to do?
>   What should I have done here?
>   What should I have done different?
>   What should I have done instead?
>   What tests should I have done?